# Insert rows in table if not found in another table

Tags: sql-server

I have a table:

```
Employee (employeeID)
EmployeeRank (rankID, employeeID)
```

Now I have another table that has all the employee's that are going to get a raise.

```
DueForRaise (rankID, employeeID)
```

I have to insert all the employees that are in DUeForRaise into the EmployeeRank table **ONLY if they are not already there with the same rank.**

I am doing this update for a particlar rankID, @rankID.

Would this work?

```
INSERT EmployeeRank ( rankID, employeeID)
SELECT rankID, employeeID
FROM DueForRaise dfr
      OUTER JOIN EmployeeRank er er.employeeid = dfr.employeeid)
WHERE dfr.rankID = @rankID
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about:

```
insert into EmployeeRank
select * from DueForRaise p
where NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT * FROM EmployeeRank WHERE rankID=p.rankID and employeeID=p.employeeID
);
```

Comment: Thanks, for a huge tables, in your opinion is this an optimized query?

Comment: It depends on the indices that you have. I would index EmployeeRank on (rankID, employeeID)

Answer (score -1):

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM EmployeeRank WHERE rankID = @rankID AND employeeID = @employeeID )

INSERT INTO EmployeeRank (rankID, employeeID) VALUES (@rankID, @employeeID)